# how can I deduce total computational time of an algorithm from CPU power

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, execution-time

I'm quite new to computer science.
I would like to know how long a CPU will take to perform an algorithm.

If a CPU has 4 cores with 2.4 gigahertz, and the algorithm has time complexity of

O(T*N^2), and specifically performs total of, say, 1000*T*N^2 number of elementary

operations, then is there a way to deduce the total time it would take to perform

1000*T*N^2 operations?

Comment: No, there is not. The total time depends on a lot more factors than just these basic numbers.

Comment: `O(n ^ 2)` is the **upper bound** of the asymptotic time-complexity of an algorithm. You can only deduce that theres some factor `c` for which the algorithm won't take more than `c * n ^ 2` operations for inputs of a certain minimum-size [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Next point: these operations cant be translated directly into CPU-time, as they depend upon factors like optimization, used language, etc.. So not possible. You could implement and benchmark though.

Comment: Aahhh makes sense. I guess it does also depend on optimization...etc